cant change font size in astra theme mobile view
I am new here and hope find solution to my issue
I have a website build with astra theme(free). the product title font size in big in the mobile view only. I tried hard to fix it using customize, or edit with Elementor. but nothing change. I am asking also if there is a way to restore the astra theme settings to the original one without using the preset button in the customizing section.
thank you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In Elementor, common CSS issues can be solved by 'regenerating CSS'
If you are 100% sure you have customised the heading on mobile view, and on the live site it is not changing, this might be the solution. Or, you need to clear your cache. Try viewing the site from Incognito. If nothing else, try some custom css, using a @media tag to target mobile screen sizes.

thank you for your reply, yes I am sure that i customised the heading on mobile view. dont know how to use @media tag. if regenerating css this is will restore the astra theme?

No, regenerate CSS doesn't reset settings. It just clears your CSS files and literally regenerates them to make sure new changes are applied. Give it a go and see if the changes show. Maybe share your site so others can inspect?
